# Kendo Asp.net columns based on entries in dictionary

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, kendo-grid, dynamic-columns

I have a very simple model with a dictionary. The number of entries of the dictionary varies from 2 to 12 and the names are also different each time (they are the same for each entry in the dictionary, but might be different for the next db-query) . How do I get columns with the keys of the dictionary and the values in the cells of the tbody?

```
public class MyModel{
    public string Name{get;set}
    public Dictionary<string, double> KeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, double>();
}
```

Here's my view

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<MyModel>()
    .Name("myGrid")
    .Columns(col =>
       {
          col.Bound(c=>c.Name);
       })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Method_In_Controller", "MyController"))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to work in ASP.NET that's why I solved it with JavaScript.

Controller: 
I made ExpandoObjects, used IDictionary and added the properties that I needed, flattened the ExpandoObjects and added them to a list and returned a JsonResult object.

JavaScript:
Got the data by AJAX request and on success generated a dynamic model, destroyed and emptied the kendoGrid and built a new kendoGrid with the data from the AJAX request and a schema with the model and a function for parse.

A huge help was:
 http://jsbin.com/viqaxoxi/1/edit?js,output